# Push YouTube video to Glassware TimeLine card using .net

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I need to add YouTube video link to my Glassware TimeLine card using .Net. I have already added this as a stream but it gets more time to upload and play.

```
    Service.Timeline.Insert(timelineItem, stream, "video/mp4").Upload();
```

Can I add this as YouTube Link.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to stream a youtube video in the timeline card, here is the C#.Net code. use this name space "YoutubeExtractor". What I am doing is resolving the stream url from the standard youtube url, then selecting the video url from that and streaming it.This works fine for me. When getting the youtube video url get the link that comes after you select share.

```
 private static String InsertItem5(MainController controller)
    {

        string link = "http://youtu.be/9uYKISlL7Vg";
        IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(link);
        VideoInfo video = videoInfos.First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 360);
        String vLink = video.DownloadUrl;


        TimelineItem critical = new TimelineItem()
        {

            Text = "Menu Card",
            BundleId = "666",
            Notification = new NotificationConfig() { Level = "DEFAULT" },
            MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>()
                                     {
                                         new MenuItem() {Action = "DELETE"},
                                     }

        };

        String mediaLink = vLink;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaLink))
        {
            Stream stream = null;
            if (mediaLink.StartsWith("/"))
            {
                stream = new StreamReader(controller.Server.MapPath(mediaLink)).BaseStream;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(mediaLink) as HttpWebRequest;

                request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;


                HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                byte[] b = null;
                using (Stream streamFromWeb = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        count = streamFromWeb.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                        ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
                    } while (streamFromWeb.CanRead && count > 0);
                    b = ms.ToArray();

                    stream = new MemoryStream(b);
                }
            }
            controller.Service.Timeline.Insert(critical, stream, "video/mp4").Upload();
        }
        else
        {
            controller.Service.Timeline.Insert(critical).Fetch();
        }
```

Reference : http://pathofacoder.com/2013/10/16/stream-you-tube-video-in-google-glass-time-line-card-using-mirror-apic-net/

Comment: Is it working now with XE12?, i'm having some problem in playing video in XE12.